# replace ereg_replace with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, ereg-replace

Hi need to change the function `ereg_replace("[\]", "", $theData)` to preg_replace

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To port `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace` you need to put the regex between a pair of **delimiter**

Also your regx is `[\]` is **invalid** to be used for preg_replace as the `\` is escaping the closing char class `]`

The correct port is

```
preg_replace('/[\\\]/','',$theData)
```

Also since the char class has just one char there is no real need of char class you can just say:

```
preg_replace('/\\\/','',$theData)
```

Since you are replace just a single char, using regex for this is not recommended. You should be using a simple text replacement using `str_replace` as:

```
str_replace('\\','',$data);
```

Comment: '/\\\/' will lead into escaping the forward slash by preg_replace, you need 4 backslashes

Comment: @Yanick, no it won't.  `preg_replace` sees it as /\\/, which it decodes as a literal backslash within delimiters.  Note that '/\\\\/' is *also* correct, because \\ and \ can both encode a backslash in a string literal.  Note that \/ is not a string escape.

Comment: A better way to explain why is because preg_replace knows the last / is a delimiter rather than a character in pattern body, so it sees 3rd backslash as a literal character. Then we know "/\\\n/" doesn't equal to "/\\\\n" since 3rd backslash will escape n.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace("\\","",$theData);
```

But I seriously doubt you need that replace at all. most likely you need some other operation.
What is this replace for?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/\\\/", "", $theData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this sed to automatically replace ereg_replace by preg_replace and put the required slashes in. Assumes no \" in the first regex

```
 sed -i 's#ereg_replace("\([^"]*\)"#preg_replace("/\1/"#g' *.php
```