# Changing function to use preg_replace() instead of ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace ereg_replace with preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649574/replace-ereg-replace-with-preg-replace)

I have got the following function within a code base that takes a String and makes links active.  I have noticed that ereg_replace() is Depreciated.  How would I change this to use preg_replace?

```
 function makeActiveLink($originalString){

        $newString = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
        return $newString;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can keep it almost exactly the same, but it would be preferable to change some things:

```
function makeActiveLink($originalString){
    $newString = preg_replace('#[a-z]+://[^<>\s]+[[a-z0-9]/]#i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $originalString);

    return $newString;
}
```

Note that I used `#` as a delimiter because you have slashes inside your string.

Comment: You can use `A-z` instead of `a-zA-Z`, or use `a-z` along with the `i` modifier to tell the regular expression engine to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeActiveLink($originalString) {
    $pattern '#[a-z]+://[^<>\s]+[[a-z0-9]/]#i';
    $newString = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="\\0" target="_blank">\\0</a>', $originalString);

    return $newString;
}
```