# What is the use of "ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j])" expression?

Tags: php, ereg

I found one PHP script for get a database backup, there use this expression to do something, that script show call to undefined function ereg_replace() this error, if i remove this line script is working fine...
how to replace this function `$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);` to that script working finely,

Can anyone assist me..

Comment: what version of PHP have you got? `ereg_replace` was deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in v7+

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649655/2960971

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the error, or what the code does?

Comment: I assume his question is "how to replace this [depreciated] function [with something that does the same so the script works correctly]".

Answer (score 1):

`ereg_replace` deprecated and remove from newer versions of php (7 and up).

You will have to update your code to use `preg_replace`

```
$row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#","\\n",$row[$j]);
```

One of the differences between ereg_replace() and preg_replace() is that the pattern must be enclosed by delimiters: delimiter + pattern + delimiter, in this case we are using **#** so we don't have to escape **/** that is the usual that is used.

Valid Delimiters:

```
 /, #, ~, +, %, @, ! , <, >
```

Reference from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

hope it helps.